# Path not filling correctly

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I have some paths that have been imported via SVG from Illustrator, and as I was splitting them up, some would fill and some wouldn't. Even after removing extra points and ensuring there wasn't any redundancy or open ends, the path still won't fill.

Even weirder, if I translate certain points enough, it will fill.

Unfilled:
[image: Unfilled]

Filled after severe deformation of an anchor:
[image: Filled after severe deformation]

What gives? I fixed the *G* earlier but now the *T* (consisting of only straight lines) won't fill. I have one other letter with many more points and I'd rather understand *why* it's doing this before spending more time fiddling with it before it works.

Comment: Could  you upload a .blend file where this is happening? It's hard to say what could be the cause without looking at it closer.

Comment: @gandalf3 <[Surely](http://www.mediafire.com/download/8sjce4n2x8ys01k/utg_so.blend)>. In the blend file I included the other letter I mentioned as well. I haven't verified the *U* yet but I'm pretty sure it's closed (it was closed in AI so unless it imported weird it should be)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object has a scale of over `40,000`. If you apply the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Scale*) everything will work correctly:

[image]

Comment: Is applying a transformation kind of re-setting the 'baseline'?

Comment: @Qix Yes, in a sense. It applies the object transforms (in this case, scale) to the actual mesh data. When you scale an object in object mode, the mesh data is not changed, but it will be distorted according to the scale in a non-destructive way (like a modifier). Since your object was scaled up by such a huge amount, you were probably seeing the result of some kind of precision/rounding error.

Comment: Aha, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you :)