# Why won't Blender let me import .svg files?

Tags: image, import

I know this seems to be a repetitive question, but nothing seems to work for me. I am trying to make two ping pong paddles to put in Blender using Inkscape. I've watched the YouTube tutorials, and I know I'm doing everything right, or so I think. But when I press import, they don't even show up. I really need to know how to do this so I can make my ping pong animation. Thanks!

My pictures:
  [image: Blue Ping Pong Paddle]
[image: Red Ping Pong Paddle]

Answer (score 12):

It works fine for me, however they come out very small initially:

[image]

Once imported and selected, you can scale them up with <kbd>S</kbd>. Once properly sized, it's also probably a [good idea to apply the scale](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8654/599) with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Also remember to delete the default cube, otherwise they will appear inside it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But when you import them, should they automatically be selected?

Comment: Never mind that. @gandalf3 When I scale them up, why does it remove all the color? Should that be happening?

Comment: It seems that your SVG has many layers stacked on top of each other. When you import this into blender, all the layers are in the exact same place, resulting in [Z-fighting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5442/599), which in turn is making the apparent color inconsistent and flickery. It's probably best to delete all but one of the layers (in either inkscape or blender), then use the *Extrude* setting to give it thickness (assuming that is what you want).

Comment: @VinceScalia This isn't quite true, the SVG imported sets the diffuse color, which is used in solid view.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure the [SVG import/export plugin](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/AI_PDF_SVG) is enabled. In the even there is no data returned check that your SVG will open in other compliant applications (e.g. GIMP, Inkscape). Compatibility can ruin your day with this one.