# Using SVG to put label on bottle

Tags: texturing

Can I use SVG artwork to put a label on a model of a vitamin bottle without first changing it to pixels? Does this need to be automated or batch processed?

Comment: The easy ways require converting to an actual image file first, as SVG files can not be use as textures in Blender.

Comment: Note that there used to be an addon for this, back in the 2.4x days: https://code.google.com/p/vectex/. But AFAIK now you'll have to use a raster image.

Comment: Maybe import, subdivide, and do a shrink-wrap modifier on it?

Answer (score 4):

Import the SVG file into blender and apply it to the bottle with a **Shrinkwrap** modifier in **Project** mode and with the bottle as Target. You might need to play with the offset value to separate the label from the surface.

[image]

[image]

Make sure this option is turned on:

[image]

make sure you read: [Why won't Blender let me import .svg files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23105/why-wont-blender-let-me-import-svg-files)

and

[Why can't I import a SVG file from Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator)