# How to place a single crisp element as an alpha while sculpting?

Tags: transparency, sculpting

This is my first question, and I am a complete newbie at using Blender (and 3D modelling suits in general).

To elaborate on my question: **the goal is to model a logo as a relief on the side of a coffee cup**. I am trying to sculpt it with an alpha.

The background and the reasoning are as follows:

The logo in question is quite elaborate, so my first idea was to:

1. import an SVG
2. convert it to mesh,
3. project the result via Shrinkwrap modifier.

However, I have found that the triangular mesh I am getting this way, wraps very poorly. I have tried recalculating it into quads with Remesh, but the results have remained suboptimal.

My second (and sadly last) idea was to:

1. rasterise my vector of the logo,
2. turn it into a BW alpha image,
3. sculpt it (like I managed to do before while messing around with
   ZBrush).

Unfortunately, using my alpha as a texture creates a multitude of blurry superimposed reliefs of my logo. I understand that this technique must be intended to create noise-like features (scratches, scales, etc.).

*But is it possible to place just one, crisp element this or similar way?*

Thanks in advance! =)

P.S. I have tried searching for the answer both on Google and this site, but failed. My apologies if this question has already been answered.

Comment: You can try using a lattice and shrinkwrap on the curves created by importing the original SVG (no need to convert it to mesh, just increase the resolution of the curves). See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface/44820#44820

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/using-svg-to-put-label-on-bottle/23647#23647

Answer (score 1):

To do this only with sculpting add the logo as the [texture mask](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/texture_tex_mask.html#texture) to the sculpting brush, switch [*Stroke* method](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/sculpt_paint/stroke_curve.html#stroke) to *Drag Dot* and draw on the object's surface.

[image: very-dithered-gif]

The texture defines a pattern according to which the brush is painting. *Drag Dot* stroke method will make brush draw only one dab preserving pattern of the texture.

Note that depending on the case you might need to continue sculpting with other stroke methods (use <kbd>E</kbd> to change) to bulge the logo out of the surface as desired. And obviously this model will be highpoly which is better to retopologize using certain methods.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is texturing.

Before you begin, please note that as far as I know, you can't use vectors in a texture, so you'll need to use a raster version of your logo. It doesn't have to be terribly high-resolution—512x512 should be just fine.

On to the details. BI is the default, but I prefer Cycles—it's much easier to get realistic results.

---

## If you're using the Blender Internal rendering engine:

- Go to the Textures tab—third from the right in the Properties panel.
- Add a new texture (or you can just use the default "Tex").
- Change the texture type to "Image or Movie".
- Add your image in the Image section. You'll have to drag it into a UV/Image Editor first.
- Change the Coordinates (in the Mapping section) to something appropriate, like UV.
- At this point, it won't know where to put the texture on your model, so you'll have to [unwrap](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important/38653#38653) it.

Everything after this is for the relief look. If you don't care about that, just skip it.

- At the top, click the second texture slot, and select the same texture from the popup. Then press the "2" button—this will duplicate the texture.
- At this point, you'll need another version of the texture image with everything opaque being white. You can use an external image editor for this.
- Set this new image as the image for the second texture.
- In the Influence panel, check the Normal option (first under Geometry) and uncheck the diffuse color option.

---

## If you're using the Cycles rendering engine:

<sub>Cycles is a more realistic-looking engine; it uses nodes (sort of like compositing) to set up materials. It also has the advantage that you don't need to make a second image to use as an alpha mask. It's what I prefer, but of course you're welcome to use BI if you want to!</sub>

- Head over to the Material tab (one left of Textures) and make sure you're using nodes. If you aren't, click the Use Nodes button in your material.
- Open a Node Editor and make sure you're in material mode (the ball in the first area, the box in the second). If this is a new material, you should see a Diffuse BSDF connected to a Material Output.
- See the side note about making the base material—you'll want to do that here.
- Add a Mix shader node between the BSDF shader node and the output. (Add it after the first Mix node if you followed the side note.)
- Add a Diffuse shader node and connect its output to the second input of the new Mix node.
- Add an Image Texture node and select your image from the popup. (You'll have to drag it into a UV/Image Editor first, and [unwrap](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important/38653#38653) your model).
- Add a Texture Coordinate node and connect the UV output to the Normal input on the texture.
- Connect the Color output of the texture node to the new Diffuse shader, and the Alpha output to the Fac of the new Mix node.

Everything after this is for the relief look. If you don't care about that, just skip it.

- Add a Bump node (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and connect its output to the Normal on the first Diffuse shader (both shaders if you followed the side note).
- Connect the Alpha output of the image texture to the Bump node.

#### Side note: The base material

You'll probably want two shaders, a Diffuse and a Glossy, connected to a Mix node. You can use the Fac on the Mix node to control the intensity of reflections in your material.