# Attaching 2d eyes to 3d head

Tags: modeling

How to attach 2D eyes to character's head? I want this eyes to fit the shape of the head.

I tried to use snap during transform (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> ) snap to face function but it looks bad. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that instead of having separate geometry (which can create problems with overlapping geometry and Z-fighting), use the images as texture on the material for the head. [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/1853)

Comment: Thanks good idea. But if i use the texture i cant animate this eyes in future.

Comment: maybe you should work with the UVWarp modifier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NlvgMYZgaY

Comment: You can use the shrinwrap modifier, but be cautions again for overlapping geometry and Z-fighting) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/using-svg-to-put-label-on-bottle/23647#23647

Comment: Thank you guys! You helped me! Very useful information.