# OSM (Open Street maps) on Blender plane

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am looking to take OSM data of roads and display it on a 2D plane. (3D objects will come later).

I have used FME to convert the data to SVG, But when I import it I get a lot of curves, but they are not visible. Probably need to to do something simple (give a a material?)

Anyway here is what the SVG file looks like: (data is in Lat Lon). The importer says this works fine. And I can view the SVG data in Chrome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-flat.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="-3.59534e-005 -3.59534e-005 0.00294818 0.00381678"><g xmlns:fme="http://www.safe.com/fme" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.000000359533915" transform="translate(0,0.00374488) scale(1, -1)">
<g id="way" >
<path fme:id="-2096" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.00267276,0.00303538 l -0.00014045,-0.000209472 -0.000138128,-0.000195737 -0.000145093,-0.000203464 -0.000106788,-0.000186295 "/>
<path fme:id="-2094" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.00186222,0.00192878 l 9.55227e-005,-8.6277e-007 "/>
<path fme:id="-2092" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.00181594,0.00192882 l -0.000128648,1.66573e-006 "/>
<path fme:id="-2090" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.00202719,0.0030487 l 4.84211e-006,-0.000327528 6.96445e-006,-0.000366579 2.32148e-006,-0.000218918 2.32148e-006,-0.000115898 "/>
<path fme:id="-2088" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.00153523,0.00321051 l -9.28593e-006,0.000169981 4.64297e-006,0.000109028 3.5983e-005,7.55467e-005 6.96445e-005,6.95373e-005 7.42874e-005,4.72166e-005 9.63415e-005,2.40375e-005 0.000117235,1.71697e-006 0.00010911,-1.11603e-005 0.000128842,-2.57545e-005 "/>
<path fme:id="-2086" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.00150738,0.00292721 l 1.04467e-005,0.00011418 "/>
<path fme:id="-2084" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.00176506,0.00288686 l -4.64296e-005,5.40851e-005 -0.000121878,0.000139076 "/>
<path fme:id="-2082" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.00160836,0.00281818 l 9.98237e-005,2.57548e-006 "/>
<path fme:id="-2080" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.00158747,0.00252801 l 7.89304e-005,3.34815e-005 6.50015e-005,4.97929e-005 4.75904e-005,5.06514e-005 2.6697e-005,7.98402e-005 "/>
<path fme:id="-2078" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.00151402,0.00275113 l -4.92461e-006,-0.000146906 7.38691e-006,-4.97781e-005 "/>
<path fme:id="-2076" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.000956723,0.00265704 l 5.58122e-005,4.00652e-005 0.000137068,8.07375e-005 0.000168257,5.15991e-005 "/>
<path fme:id="-2074" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.000943283,0.00225656 l 0.000206612,7.38312e-005 0.00021938,7.81236e-005 "/>
<path fme:id="-2072" fme:visible="true" d="M 0.000316483,0.000195263 l 8.12519e-005,-3.86339e-005 9.51808e-005,-2.66145e-005 0.000114913,-6.86826e-006 0.000113753,8.58532e-006 0.000314561,4.0351e-005 "/>
```

Comment: if you get a lot of curves but can't see them you might have an issue with the scale on the svg curves. read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23105/why-wont-blender-let-me-import-svg-files slect any of the curves in the oultiner and press numpad . (period) read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file.  If the curves are too large you might need to change your clip point.

Comment: Looks from the data the svg curves will be on small scale rather than too large.  (all < 0.003) The addon https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-geo will generate roads (as a mesh) straight from the OSM file, which can be converted to curves easilly.