# How do I extrude an imported svg along the z axis without clipping the original shapes?

Tags: import

I have imported an svg and I am using the tutorials here: http://spolearninglab.com/curriculum/software/3d_modeling/blender/blender_02.html

and here: 
https://studiogreenleaf.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/inkscape-to-blender/

It seems pretty straightforward, and I even got it to work with one shape, but other shapes are truncated or clipped in strange ways.

For instance, this original svg is simple:

[image: energy node]

But then when I import it into blender using the above method I get this:

[image]

Another one I have is even more strange.  Original:

[image]

But then in blender using import svg and extrusion:

[image]

Would love to know what I am doing wrong here!  I have gone over both articles several times and not really sure what else to try.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Here are the svg files for reference -

http://elephantlaboratories.com/svg/sol-energy-node.svg

http://elephantlaboratories.com/svg/sol-transmit-tower.svg

Comment: What blender version are you using? I can't seem to recreate your error, importing these files works fine with my blender 2.73 at home. The object is initially tiny, but when scaled x1000 is fine. I thought this might be related to the fact these files are exported from illustrator, but I opened and re-saved them through inkscape, which generates more orderly and explicit SVG, and it made no difference on the end result.

Comment: I am using blender 2.71... I will try to update blender and let you know.

Comment: works here.. after first scaling it up.. and applying the scale, then extrude by a really small amount..  http://i.stack.imgur.com/usqgW.png

Comment: This is due to precision errors of un-applied scale. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8654/599

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23106/599

Comment: I had the same problem, but knowing about Inkscape, I'll give it a go. Nice tip btw!
I had been using Illustrator's export to .svg. Is there a similar setting that should be applied prior to export? And yes, the .svg imported into Blender 2.73a
is tiny, tiny, tiny. Have to scale a huge amount with the above described distortions and artifacts.
Good topic, thanks for posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sort of thing can happen when your object has a [very extreme scale](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8654/599).

To fix it, apply the scale with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Apply Scale*.

[image]

When you scale an object in object mode the mesh data is not changed, but it will be distorted according to the scale in a non-destructive way (like a modifier). Since your object was scaled up by such a huge amount, it caused some distortion; probably due to precision error.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to point out here that the right way to do this is to be aware of the output scale settings in your *Vector Graphics* application. While the problem here isn't Blender, it is a reoccurring question and I feel it's worth explaining.

In the case of Inkscape it's easy to set the document properties to Meters as it comes closest to the Blender's default grid dimensions.

- In Inkscape: *File -> Document properties* and set it to *Meters*.

See here, the inkscape scale is represented in M. (but you need to choose that from the drop-down seperately to see it in the Inkscape Viewport)

[image]

If you do that right, there's no need to rescale / apply. The SVG should import at the right size.