# how should I go about creating this?

Tags: mesh

I want to make this: [image: mang]

Just the mesh, not the texture. But in 3d of course. It's supposed to be a plush (animal).

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63246/how-do-i-make-a-3-dimensional-character-out-of-flat-picture/ also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39044/making-3d-object-from-a-svg-file and

Comment: You know that is an almost flat image. One way could be importit as plane or svg, and just extrude it to give it some depth... if you need a "cartoonish horse head" instead, you'll need to model it from scratch, using that image as a reference....