# Why are my SVG imports so small?

Tags: import

I'm definitely a newbie with blender still, as I've dipped my toe in a bit being a video editor.  My issue is importing .svg saved from illustrator.  Just simple vectors with not too many paths.  Just a thick text company logo.  I want to bring in and extrude, light, etc.  I've done it before in older versions of blender with no problem.  Am I not doing something right? Can someone tell me how to get an eps saved as an svg from illustrator to size correctly?

Comment: there's an answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35995/47 (question isn't the same, but the answer is)

Answer (score 6):

The Grid Plane in Blender by default is *1m X 1m* for every square. When you make a Vector drawing usually your Vector Editor (Illustrator / Inkscape) will be set to something standard like A4 or A3. The longest side of an A4 is about 30 cm. (one third of a meter), an svg the size of A4 would look like this in your Vector Editor.

[image]

Imported in Blender that looks like this:

[image]

SVG drawings are based on Scalar values, but when you use Vector graphics in a layout program or import into something like Blender the program needs to know what kind of world-dimensions the shape has. It's either pixels, cm, inches, meters, etc.

***In Illustrator***

You might have a tick-box checked to make your .svg export 'responsive'. From what I read this will omit any *width / height / units* information -- it assumes you want to use the .svg on the web or something. For more insight about how Illustrator saves / exports .svg files I recommend their built-in manual or support site.

***In Blender***

currently when the default SVG importer (io_curve_svg) encounters an .svg which has no dimensions or 'SVGUnits' it will treat the coordinates the same as it would if you had set the units to pixels in your Vector Editor.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate and richly illustrated answer! Having encounterd this problem countless of times, I searched S.E. and followed along with your advice. However, it still scales wrongly. I tested by making my svg 1000x1000 mm (width="1000.4mm"  height="1000.4mm" ) and adding a rectangle of that size. However, in Blender, this rectangle becomes exactly (!) 1.25 m. Well, I can scale now everything to 80% and everything is fine,... but,... is there something I am missing?