# Cannot Import .SVG File

Tags: import, file-format

I cannot import an .svg file into Blender. I have tried other files and they work. I have checked the User Preferences and the "import SVG" option is enabled.

How can I tell if this one .svg file is formatted correctly for Blender?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape

Comment: What was the SVG created in? Did you make it, or was it downloaded from somewhere? Do other SVG files import fine?

Also, if you run Blender from the terminal, add-ons will often report errors there. So if you run Blender from the terminal and try to import this SVG, do you see any errors?

Comment: Other related links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44520/why-are-my-svg-imports-so-small/44555#44555 and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/imported-svg-files-does-not-show-up

Comment: Clarification - this file was created in Illustrator. It was done by a graphic designer I paid to convert a jpeg log into an SVG file. I am guessing that I should have asked for vector paths.

Comment: Follow up question - can I import full color SVG files?

Comment: As long as your SVG file contains paths (vectors) the color for them should be imported.

Comment: @jawinn if you use inkscape you can load the jpeg file and trace it there [see this link](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/tracing/tutorial-tracing.en.html)

Answer (score 2):

To import an SVG file go to *File > Import > Scalable Vector Graphics(SVG)*

[image]

**Make sure that the SVG file you are importing contains vectors (paths)** Blender cannot import raster data or text directly form SVG files. In other words, **the information on the SVG has to be traced**. For a detailed explanation [read this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23171/1853)

If the plugin is not enabled for any reason go to the User Preferences Window (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and enable it there.

It is also possible that your file is importing successfully but is so small that is hard to see on the viewport. Check if the [outliner](https://www.blender.org/manual/_images/Outliner-Window.jpg) shows one or more curve objects. [image]

If so, select one of the curves and press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> to move the view to selected. Then you should be able to see the object.

Comment: I see more than one curve. However, I only see a tiny dot in the middle of the main editor. I tried selecting the dot and scaling the image, but the dot just moves around.

Comment: Select the curve on the oultliner with a right click and choose select. Then on the 3D viewport press numpad . (period) to have the veiwport zoomed on your object.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet that you have a rasterized image that's been embedded in an SVG file.

When Blender imports an SVG, it takes the spline curves that define the vector graphic in the file, and convert them to splines (or a mesh) to define it in 3D. Unfortunately, you can have a rasterized (pixel-based, instead of vector-based) image embedded in an SVG project. That image will not be imported by Blender because it doesn't have any splines or vectors.

You can check this by opening the file in an SVG editor (like Inkscape or Illustrator) and trying to select the vectors that define the borders. If you can't select any edges, then zoom in super close and see if you start seeing pixels. If you start seeing pixels, then it's rasterized, not vectorized.

If that's actually the case, then this IS a duplicate of [Why can't I import a SVG file from Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape)

I hope that helps!

Comment: I was able to load the image into Inkscape. I don't see any pixels. The image is huge though. It is 5 megs. When I get it loaded into Inkscape, it covers the Inkscape canvas. Imagine a pillow covering a postage stamp. My image is the pillow.

Comment: More info. My image used a combination of vector and rasterized elements. I am guessing this is my issue. Would I have to have the image redone into 100% vector to make everything work? Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, anything that you want to import will have to be vectorized. Look into Trace Bitmap. Inkscape can do that, and Illustrator can, too. You could also just trace it in Blender ;-)

Answer (score 0):

when you save as an SVG from illustrator use the settings below in the open dialog window
[image: Illustrator setting]

Answer (score 0):

I'm more than 20 years in IT, but Blender every day joke me :)

It is just placed new imported objects in so unexpected places, so I usually spend few minutes, to figure out, where new object appear.

And for semi-3D objects things are more complicated.

I mean, objects like imported 2D images and DXF, because they usually imported as tiny 2D rectangle, aligned edge to view, so literally looks as line segment with zero width (when selected shown as yellow or orange line segment, and in ortho view nothing shown when not selected).

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out, how to find this object, I usually zoom-out so see all objects, and select it from outliner, and than rotating view and looking for yellow line segment.

Only two things helpful - I'm careful pupil and nearly always import in flat ortho view (I prefer front ortho or top ortho, but right ortho also good), so all times imported object aligned with two axis.

And second, when import I place center of viewport close to zero coordinates, and new object is appeared not far from 3D cursor (depends on size of svg image outline, but usually within classic first Blender cube, 1 blender units size).
It is easier to find knowing this.

As I import svg to emboss it, than I choose from menu: object->convert to mesh from curve...

And than switch to edit mode and extrude along normal, and now it become new blender citizen with all 3D rights :)

Sure, better to import such semi-3D object into empty blender project, than make all need transforms with it; make it complete 3D object; save as .blend file and than import from these .blend file as from library.