# SVG file consisting of curves does not import into Blender

Tags: bezier-curves, import, image, svg

Importing https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Bitcoin.svg, a file which looking at the source code appears to be made of paths and have no raster images in it, does not make any objects appear, either in the viewport, or in the list of objects, when I import it into Blender 2.79b. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening, and how I can fix it?

Edit: The question linked as a possible duplicate does not solve this, because again, this file only has curves, not rasters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Import .SVG File](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/cannot-import-svg-file)

Comment: That svg file works fine in blender 2.7b here on linux.

Comment: Strange. I will try in a different file with a different rendering engine.