# SVG Import Scale

Tags: import, workflow

I created SVG file by laser slicer addon at 96dpi as default. I then for certain reason, imported back into blender,  the dimensions are not correct. and is always around 6.7% more. By calculation, the importer may have used 90dpi for calculation. Is there any way to correct this scale problem without scale the imported object, or export 2nd time at 90dpi?

This is similar to other import svg problem, but most answers solve by scaling before export.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44520/why-are-my-svg-imports-so-small

Comment: This tells me that blender handles svg without unit as pixel. I also googled SVGUnits, and a page tells me that SVG specification's default is 90dpi. This still does not solve my problem.